# PHP: Concatinating two array values

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays:

```
array(1,2,3,4,5)
array(10,9,8,7,6)
```

Final array Needed:

```
array(0=>1:10,1=>2:9,2=>3:8,3=>4:7,4=>5:6)
```

I can write a custom function which would be quieck enough!! But i wanted to use a existing one so Is there already any function that does this in php? Pass the two input arrays and get the final array result? I read through the [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) but couldn't find any or combination of function that would provide me the result

Comment: The result should be `1:10` or `1,10`?

Comment: Please see my edited final array. Thanks for all our valuable replys :)

Answer (score 4):

No built in function but really there is nothing wrong with `loop` .. Just keep it simple

```
$c = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i ++) {
    $c[] = sprintf("%d:%d", $a[$i], $b[$i]);
}
```

or use `array_map`

```
$c = array_map(function ($a,$b) {
    return sprintf("%d:%d", $a,$b);
}, $a, $b);
```

[Live Demo](http://eval.in/31752)

Comment: O sorry I thought it was javascript since you're using inline functions (didn't knew that was possible in PHP!)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$arr1   = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr2   = array(10,9,8,7,6);

$res    = array_map(null,$arr1,$arr2);
$result = array_map('implode', array_fill(0, count($res), ':'), $res);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1:10
    [1] => 2:9
    [2] => 3:8
    [3] => 4:7
    [4] => 5:6
)
```

Comment: +1 But you don't need `array_fill` ... implode would do just fine

Answer (score 0):

See: http://php.net/functions

And especially: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Also, I don't quite understand the final array result?
Do you mean this:

```
array (1 = 10, 2 = 9, 3 = 8, 4 = 7, 5 = 6)
```

Because in that case you'll have to write a custom function which loops through the both arrays and combine item[x] from array 1 with item[x] from array 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $arr1=array(1,2,3,4,5);
  $arr2=array(10,9,8,7,6);
  for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
    $newarr[]=$arr1[$i].":".$arr2[$i];
 }
 print_r($newarr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_combine

```
array_combine($array1, $array2)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php